# HTML5 Canvas higlight and unhilight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

In my application then draw some text on a canvas .
For highlighting the text they are computing the enclosing rectangle and filling it with some 
opacity factor 
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.3)";
context.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);

This is able to mock highlighting of text .

Now i want to un hilight that text .So what i thought was to use add the complement rgb factor wiich will sum up to white but it is not working .
for above code it would be 
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,0,0.3)";
context.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);

Am i doing it right or any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would in this case do:

```
var oldRect = context.getImageData(rect.x-1, rect.y-1, rect.w+2, rect.h+2);
context.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
```

to restore:

```
context.putImageData(oldRect, rect.x-1, rect.y-1);
```

Why -1 and +2 ? that is to consider anti-aliased pixels as your rectangle would most likely be drawn at a half pixel offset (default coordinate system draw from center of a pixel and not from its corner which will trigger sub-pixeling/anti-aliasing) so to make sure that extra part is included expand the rectangle a little for the image data.

One challenge that may occur is if you draw images onto the canvas from other origins than the page (CORS restriction). This would, if not fulfilled, prevent you from being able to retrieve the image data. Besides from that there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find compositing options very useful for this sort of "unhighlighting".

I would suggest either:

1. put your highlights on a second canvas that overlays the first, or
2. redraw your canvas from scratch when the highlight is removed, or
3. take a copy of the canvas (using `ctxgetImageData`) and restore that when the highlight is removed